# DateTimePicker Bootstrap size of year selection part

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

Then i try to change year in Bootstrap DateTimePicker i see the strange result - yers shows in one line and out of widget borders. How it can be fixed?

[attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFEl.png)

Comment: Your custom styles are conflicting with dataTime picker styles or you have not used plugin properly. Please post your code.

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: Thanks for idea about conflict  my custom style and dataTime picker styles! i found the source of the issue in my css file!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

use it. if posible please attached the code:)